# Bench init error related to virtualenv [mac os]

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, erpnext

i was trying to init a bench on fresh insall of ERPnext, i m new to the framework and my probleme prolly is a missinstall but i cant really face it here is a snipper of my console output :

virtualenv : 16.6.0

[View screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOK1a.png)

$ => bench init onlinebook

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2580, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 831, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1106, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1568, in install_python
    shutil.copy(original_python, py_executable)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copyfile
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 88, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 96, in samefile
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

has anyone faced something like this before? it may or may not be related to ERPnext but i'm really stuck here

Comment: Please copy-paste the full stack trace into the question, rather than posting a screenshot. Some users might not be able to access the link

Comment: done, thank you C.nivs

Comment: A quick Google Search for that error message returns plenty of results, have you already consulted those?

Comment: trust me i spent a whole day reading those, but thanks